# Why window.open(someURL) throwing open redirects security vurnerability in React?

Tags: reactjs, security, websecurity

This is my code
window.open(
`${process.env.REACT_APP_APACHE_SUPERSET_URL}/superset/sqllab/`,
"_blank"
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vulnerability is not only for React.JS but also it's dangerous for other frameworks when using it. The vulnerability can be explained as it occurs when an application allows a user to control a redirect or forward to another URL. If the app does not validate untrusted user input, an attacker could supply a URL that redirects an unsuspecting victim from a legitimate domain to an attacker’s phishing site.

Comment: How to validate the URL??

Comment: You can use this code block

[JS Code](https://jsfiddle.net/bseq3up0/)